# Ensuring template argument type matches that of its variadic constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-functions, enable-if

I would like to have a class like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T* data_;

    template<typename... Ts, std::enable_if<std::is_same<T,Ts>...>...>
    explicit Foo(Ts...ts) : data_{ ts... } {}
};
```

However; something with the syntax is wrong, and I'm not sure if you can set parameters into a pointer directly like this upon initialization.

What I would like for this to do is simply this:

```
Foo<int> f1{ 1, 3, 5, 7 }; // Or
// Foo<int> f1( 1, 3, 5 7 );
// f1.data_[0] = 1
// f1.data_[1] = 3
// f1.data_[2] = 5
// f1.data_[3] = 7
// f1.data_[4] = ... not our memory either garbage or undefined...

Foo<float> f2{ 3.5f, 7.2f, 9.8f }; // Or
// Foo<float> f2( 3.5f, 7.2f, 9.8f );
// f2.data_[0] = 3.5
// f2.data_[1] = 7.2
// f2.data_[2] = 9.8
// f2.data_[3] = ... not our memory
```

I would also like to have the constructor check to make sure that each and every parameter that is passed into the constructor is of type `<T>`; simply put for each `Ts` it must be a `T`.

I might be overthinking this but for the life of me I can not get this or something similar to compile. I don't know if it's within `enable_if`, `is_same` or through the class's initializer list and trying to store the contents into a pointer. I don't know if I should use an array of `T` instead but the array's size won't be known until the arguments are passed into the constructor. I'm also trying to do this without using a basic container such as `std::vector`; it's more for self education than practical source code. I just want to see how this could be done with raw pointers.

---

**Edit**

I've changed my class to something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T* data_;

    template<typename... Ts, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, Ts...>::value>* = nullptr>
    explicit Foo( const Ts&&... ts ) : data_{ std::move(ts)... } {}
 };
```

And when trying to use it:

```
 int a = 1, b = 3, c = 5, d = 7;
 Foo<int> f1( a, b, c, d );
 Foo<int> f2{ a, b, c, d };
```

I'm a little closer with this iteration; but they both give different compiler errors.

- The first being: `C2661`: *"No overloaded function takes 4 arguments"*
- And the second:  `C2440`: *"initializing, cannot convert from initializer list to Container, no constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous."*

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use a `std::initialize_list:`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
  std::vector<T> data_;

  explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<T> data) : data_(data)
  {
    std::cout << "1";
  };

  template <typename... Ts,
            typename ENABLE=std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T,Ts> && ...)> >
  explicit Foo(Ts... ts) : Foo(std::initializer_list<T>{ts...})
  {
    std::cout << "2";
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo<int> f1{1, 3, 5, 7}; // prints 1
  Foo<int> f2(1, 3, 5, 7); // prints 1 then 2

  return 0;
}
```

If some `Ts` are different from `T` you will get a compile-time error.

With

```
gcc -std=c++17  prog.cpp
```

you get:

```
  Foo<int> f1{1, 3, 5., 7};
```

> error: narrowing conversion of ‘5.0e+0’ from ‘double’ to ‘int’ inside
>   { } [-Wnarrowing]    Foo f1{1, 3, 5., 7};
>                             ^

and

```
Foo<int> f2(1, 3, 5., 7);
```

you get

> error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo::Foo(int, int,
>   double, int)’    Foo f2(1, 3, 5., 7);
>                             ^ note: candidate: ‘template Foo::Foo(Ts ...)’    explicit Foo(Ts... ts) :
>   Foo(std::initializer_list{ts...})
>
> ...

**Update:** if you really want to use something like *raw pointer*, here is a complete working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
  size_t n_;
  std::unique_ptr<T[]> data_;

  explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<T> data) : n_(data.size()), data_(new T[n_])
  {
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), data_.get());
    std::cout << "1";
  };

  template <typename... Ts, typename ENABLE = std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...)> >
  explicit Foo(Ts... ts) : Foo(std::initializer_list<T>{ts...})
  {
    std::cout << "2";
  }

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo<T>& toPrint)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < toPrint.n_; i++)
      std::cout << "\n" << toPrint.data_[i];
    return out;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo<int> f1{1, 3, 5, 7};  // prints 1
  Foo<int> f2(1, 3, 5, 7);  // prints 1,2

  std::cout << f1;
  std::cout << f2;

  return 0;
}
```

I let you replace unique_ptr by a raw pointer with all the extra work: delete[] etc...

Comment: This would work for the initializer list, but what about the constructor too? Also I stated that I'm not using an internal container such as vector, I'm using a raw pointer!

Comment: @FrancisCugler ok, sorry I did not have seen your f(1,2,3..) requirement.. Hold on I wil think about that

Comment: I know I could of used `vector` all of this time, but I wasn't in this particular case as it is self educational and is for demonstration purposes. My question was more on the lines of getting `enable_if` and `is_same` to work properly so that my constructor can be variadic while the template itself isn't making sure that each type that is passed into the constructor is the same type as that of the template. Then it was a matter of storing the individual contents from the constructor arguments into its internal pointer of that type....

Comment: @FrancisCugler I understand no problem. It's just that using unique or shared ptr is safer concerning memory leaks etc...

Comment: ... I know I wasn't reserving memory for the temporaries for I would have to use new and delete at some point. I was also interested in using the class's constructor's initializer list to initialize the pointer to those values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193940/discussion-between-francis-cugler-and-picaud-vincent).

Comment: Yeah I could of used `unique_ptr`, but for demonstration purposes it's not needed. In real code I wouldn't even bother with `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` and just use `vector`, `list`, `array`, or `map` of those types, unless if I really needed to extended the life time of the members then I would use smart pointers.

Comment: I've been around the C++ language for quite some time; 100% self taught. I'd say my skill level is that of intermediate to almost expert, but there are some things that I struggle to grasp and templates took me a while to learn, then once I started to get the hang of them c++14 and 17 came out with variadic types, and now I'm starting to learn patterns such as SFINAE and I'm experimenting with `is_same`, `enable_if`, etc. to get a better feel for their proper syntax and context of use.

Comment: ok, that's fine. A good reference is [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). If everything is ok now, sorry I have to go. Good learning!

Answer (score 2):

`std::is_same` only compares two types, and you can't use pack expansions to declare multiple template parameters.  That means you'll need to pull all of your `std::is_same` checks out into another check:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct all_same : std::bool_constant<(std::is_same<T, Ts>::value && ...)> {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    std::vector<T> data_;

    template <typename... Ts, std::enable_if_t<all_same<T, std::decay_t<Ts>...>::value>* = nullptr>
    Foo(Ts&&... ts)
        : data_{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}
    {
    }
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/890e7a0fd746ad29)

You also need to allocate memory for your `data_` array.  Here I've used `std::vector` to take care of that allocation for me, but you could use `new[]` and `delete[]` to manage it yourself if you really want to.

Answer (score 1):

`enable_if` and `is_same` won't store anything anywhere, they are only compile-time constructs and do not yield to any code in the binary executable.

Regardless of the syntax, what your code is essentially doing is trying to take the address of a constructor argument (which is a temporary). This will be a dangling pointer as soon as the constructor exits.

Either `Foo` owns the memory area and must allocate in constructor and delete in destructor (if any doubt: use `std::vector`!), or it aliases some external memory, and must receive a pointer to that memory.

Now regarding syntax:

- `std::is_same` is a template that provides a `value` boolean constant and is to be used like so: `std::is_same<T1, T2>::value`. Alternatively you can use `std::is_same_v<T1, T2>`.
- `std::enable_if` provides a `type` type member, only if the constant expression (1st template parameter) is true. Use it like `std::enable_if<expr, T>::type`. If `expr` is true, `type` is a typedef to `T`. Otherwise it is not defined and yields a substitution failure. Alternatively you can use `std::enable_if_t<expr, T>`

You can have a look [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2019/01/25/variadic-number-function-parameters-type/) for a similar approach of yours.

But you can also simplify all this by using a member vector. In that case, the vector constructor ensures that all arguments have compatible types. Here is a complete example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    vector<T> data_;

    template<typename ...Ts>
    explicit Foo(Ts... ts) : data_{ ts... } {}

    void print() {
        for (const auto &v : data_) {
            cout << v << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main() {

    Foo<int> ints { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Foo<string> strings { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"};
    // Foo<string> incorrect { "a", 2, "c", 4, "e"};

    ints.print();
    strings.print();
    // incorrect.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of `enable_if` and `is_same`. I know that I can easily use a `vector`, but that wasn't what I was asking for. I stated that this was merely self educational and not practical. I did kind of figure that I wasn't allocating memory for the temporaries in which, new and delete would have to be used somewhere, but it was more on the lines of getting enable_if and is_same to work so that the constructor can be variadic while the template itself isn't. I have my reasons for not using vector in this case; it's for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

The most idiomatic way to do this in C++17 is using `std::cunjunction_v`. It lazily evaluates subsequent values and allows you to avoid fold expressions. Also  messages generated by the compiler are the same for both of casese you mentioned in edited piece of code.

Also, passing data by const-rvalue-ref makes no sense, since it is impossible to move data from const objects. Additionaly you were moving pack of arguments to a pointer. I didn't know what to do about it so just removed it.

Additionaly, take a look at the `std::decay_t` - without it it would not work, as sometimes `Ts` is deduced not as `int` but as `const int &` or `int &`. This leads to `std::is_same_v` being false.

The code below compiles fine at godbolt:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    T* data_;

    template<
        typename... Ts,
        std::enable_if_t<
            std::conjunction_v<
                std::is_same<T, std::decay_t<Ts>>...
            >
        > * = nullptr
    >
    explicit Foo( Ts&&... ts ) : data_{ } {}
 };
```